# Add class via command line

Tags: java, android, command-line, sdk

Classes can be added to an Android project in Eclipse via New -> Class, and this will supposedly add it to the project somehow, but how can I do this via the command line? I set up the class in src/(reverse.dns.path)/CLASS.java, but I couldn't find anything in http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html, but I would appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command for adding class from command line. Just add necessary .java file with a text editor. Java compiler will compile that class.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools to create java classes in an Android project. You can however create [a new android project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) with the sdk tools and modify it to some extent.

Well, if you really want to do it via the command line:

```
$ cd myapplication/
$ cd src/
$ cd main/java/my/package/name/
```

Create the java class:

```
$ touch SomeClass.java
```

Add package and the class declaration to the java file:

```
$ echo "package my.package.name;" >> SomeClass.java 
$ echo "public class SomeClass {}" >> SomeClass.java
```

If you want to create another package:

```
$ mkdir somepackage
$ cd somepackage
$ touch AnotherClass.java
```

Now if you go into Eclipse everything should be updated.